# How to actually use Twitter provider in Kohana?

Tags: twitter, kohana-3, twitter-oauth

There are no clear docs or anything. shadowhand's demo repo is broken. How to actually use Twitter Oauth provider in Kohana 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit complicated, but the steps basically are:

1. Build an OAuth_Consumer
2. Build a OAuth_Provider (twitter)
3. Get a request token
4. Redirect them to the authorize_url
5. Get the callback
6. Exchange the request token for an access token
7. Make API calls

Here's an example controller that does all of that: https://gist.github.com/1267793